# how to check if maven-install-plugin is available?

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install ojdbc using maven install:install-file, with the command:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

From a ubuntu ec2-server and a cygwin command prompt, this works great.
From a third ubuntu 14.04 terminal running maven 3.2.5 and java 8, this fails with the error

```
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute, but there is no POM in this directory (/home/user). PLease verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory
```

Technically, the error message is correct, I'm executing this from the directory containing the jarfile, and there is no pom in there. But install:install-file doesn't require a pom on any of the other servers I've tested the command on.

Is there a way to check that the maven-install-plugin is available? How to correct if it is not?

Comment: It's not that the plugin is not available. It will be downloaded. But it shouldn't throw that error.

Comment: Indeed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your command was `mvn install:install-file`?

Comment: yes - I'm copy-and-pasting between terminals.  Works on 2 out of 3.

Comment: Your settings.xml is all right? Correct connection to the repository?

Comment: Try cleaning the m2 repo and redo that command. This is not possible.

Comment: Possibly not?  I manually upped the maven version meaning that I installed a later version than apt-get install pointed me to.  Checking

Comment: Interesting. There is both an /etc/maven/settings.xml and /etc/maven2/settings.xml, and they disagree with eachother.   Maybe uninstall maven entirely and start over there?

Comment: Clean and restart from scratch seems like a good idea with those problems that shouldn't happen in the first place ;)!

Comment: and we're good. When in doubt, reboot. Thank you.